# scheduled alarm to repeat every minute of the clock android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have an app which requires a code to be executed every minute. But the issue is that the code has to be executed at every minute change of the clock. Which means,

If its 12:34 then the code will execute at 12:35 and goes on. But my current code works but it includes the seconds. Meaning,

If its 12:34:30 and the alarm starts, the code is executed. But the code is then executed at 12:35:30.

I want the code to be executed each minute according to the clock of the phone. Below is the current code.

```
 Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyABService.class);
                PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent2, 0);
                AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarm_manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, c.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 1000, pintent);
```

Im making it execute every second so that the effect takes place at the exact time. Instead of having it every second i need it to repeat itself at every minute change of the clock (every minute)

How do i go about this

Comment: If you only need this while your app is running and the screen is on, use in-process solutions like `ScheduledExecutorService`. If you are looking for this to work even if your app's process was terminated or the screen is not on, give up and write some other app, as Android does not support your scenario on Android 6.0+.

Answer (score 13):

Use [Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK) This is a broadcast intent fired every minute by the Android OS. Register to it as you would register to a normal system broadcast in code (doesn't work from manifest)

```
tickReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)==0)
    {
      //do something
    }
  };

  //Register the broadcast receiver to receive TIME_TICK
  registerReceiver(tickReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
```

[This](http://sourabhsoni.com/how-to-use-intent-action_time_tick/) article describes the complete process.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Calendar to set the time to trigger to the next full minute, and repeat it every minute (60*1000ms)

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

long triggerAt = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
long repeatAfter = 60 * 1000;

alarm_manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, triggerAt, repeatAfter, pintent);
```

Comment: So will it be executed the moment this setRepeating is called? Like if the alarm is set at 11:23 then will it also be executed at 11:23 or will it execute only at 11:24

Comment: This way it will be triggered at  the next full minute, so 11.24

Comment: If you want to start at 11.23, you set calendar.minute to 0 instead of add 1

Comment: If i set calendar.minute to 1, the service(what i want to execute every minute) is executed at every 20-50 seconds. its random between 20-50. If i set the minute to 0, it doesnt work at all. The service is not executed

Comment: @AxeManTOBO is your app running while you are testing? You may need to use `RTC_WAKEUP`. If you are running on android 6.0+ you need to prepare for doze and standby mode

Comment: Yes, The app is running while im testing it. RTC_WAKEUP? What will that do

Comment: @AxeManTOBO wake up the cpu if needed. Are you using android 6.0 ?

Comment: Nope. Tested it on android KK

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AnyClass.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

Hope this code solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use the Quartz Schedular API, make the corn job which run at every min.

```
 “0 0/1 * * * ?” // Corn expression run at  every min
```

Build the Schedular and trigger like that

```
     SchedulerFactory schedFact = new  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory();

     Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();

     sched.start();

   // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
   JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)
  .withIdentity("myJob", "group1")
  .build();

  // Trigger the job to run now, and then every 1 min
    Trigger trigger =trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?"))
    .forJob("myJob", "group1")
    .build();

   // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
    sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

and write your code in HelloJob class

```
 public class HelloJob implements Job {

  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
  throws JobExecutionException;

 // Here you write your code which exceute on every min
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK.

Broadcast Action: The current time has changed. Sent every minute. You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().

Source:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK

```
IntentFilter tickIntent = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
        // perform per minute task
    }
};
registerReceiver(receiver, tickIntent);
```

Comment: my mistake @TimCastelijns

Answer (score -2):

You can use below code for your requirement,

```
    Calendar initialCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    initialCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    initialCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    long triggerAtMillis = initialCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
    long intervalMillis = 60 * 1000;

    alarm_manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, triggerAtMillis, intervalMillis, pintent);
```

Comment: Thanks for repeating my answer